# Naive Bayes classifier - accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, naivebayes, bayesian-networks

I'm using Naive Bayes classifier in Weka on a data set of 7000 instances with 15 attributes. My baseline accuracy is 87.5% using ZeroR. As a part of data  preprocessing I normalized the data set with zero mean and unit variance, applied filter to randomize the dataset. I've used training (70%) and testing (30%) sets, as well as 10-fold cross validation on the entire data set, used supervised discretization and attribute selection and the best accuracy of the classifier I got is 93.43%. Is this small improvement in respect to baseline accuracy?

Comment: Half as many cases are being classified incorrectly using Naive Bayes over ZeroR.  Also, 87.5% seems quite high for ZeroR.  Are most of the cases a single class?

Comment: Yes, out of 7000 instances, 6131 belong to one class, the rest of the instances to the other class. Hence, ZeroR (which always guesses more probable class) has 87.5% accuracy (6131/7000).

Comment: Would it be possible for you to switch to another performance measure that is more robust for skewed classes? Like MCC or AUC?

Comment: How robust is AUC for skewed classes? How about area under PR curve?